# How to make images responsive with Bootstrap and use it on wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I tired to make WordPress featured image responsive with bootstrap. The way to make the image responsive with bootstrap is

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

I tired to use this method in wordpress when showing the featured image dynamically.

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'jumbo_thumbnail'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

But it doesnot work. I know if I put a link there instead of `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'jumbo_thumbnail'); ?>` it will work. But I am dynamically getting the featured image, and this method doesnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Get rid of your `img` tag altogether and use this:

```
<?php
the_post_thumbnail( 'jumbo_thumbnail', array(
    'alt' => 'Responsive image',
    'class' => 'img-responsive'
) );
?>
```

`the_post_thumbnail` function will output the `img` tag for you.